# Jquery : Is it possible to make customized menu using devexpress?

Tags: jquery, html, css, devexpress, devextreme

I have been wondering if we could customize menu using devexpress. Currently the menu that i can done is only horizontal or vertical. But what if i required a customized menu in the below format. Even though i tried i was not that successful.

This is what i require:

[image]

Below is the code i have tried which currently gives me horizontal menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="description" content="carousel expanding">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Check</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.5/css/dx.spa.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.5/css/dx.common.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.5/css/dx.light.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="myDevClass" id="menu"></div>

<script>
// For DevExpress Menu
               var menuItems = [
                                {
                                    text: "Animal",
                                    items: [
                                        { text: "Cat" },
                                        { text: "Dog" },
                                        { text: "Elephant" },
                                        { text: "Lion" },
                                        { text: "Tiger" },
                                        { text: "Cow" }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Birds",
                                    items: [
                                        { text: "Peigion" },
                                        { text: "Crow" },
                                        { text: "Mynah" },
                                        { text: "Swan" },
                                        { text: "Sparrow" },
                                        { text: "Humming Bird" }
                                    ]
                                }

                            ];
                            $(function () {
                                $("#menu").dxMenu({
                                    items: menuItems
                                });
                            });
</script>
```

I didnt find any study material for the same. Can i acheive it using some Jquery or so?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a grouped dxList for this purpose:

```
$("#list").dxList({
    items: [
        {
            key: "Animal",
            items: [
                { text: "Cat" },
                { text: "Dog" },
                { text: "Elephant" },
                { text: "Lion" },
                { text: "Tiger" },
                { text: "Cow" }
            ]
        },
        {
            key: "Birds",
            items: [
                { text: "Peigion" },
                { text: "Crow" },
                { text: "Mynah" },
                { text: "Swan" },
                { text: "Sparrow" },
                { text: "Humming Bird" }
            ]
        }
    ],
    grouped: true
});
```

Also, use the custom CSS rules for the "dx-list-group" and "dx-list-item" class to change menu styles